# @react-native-firebase/admob is not working in IOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase

I am using **@react-native-firebase/admob** for displaying add on app. It is working fine in Android but when I am using it on ios then app is crash with following error.

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift-5.0/iphonesimulator'
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___isPlatformVersionAtLeast", referenced from:
      -[APMMeasurement reportFirstOpenOnWorkerQueue] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMMeasurement_d6638b533a7cdc437824cf7209ad695a.o)
      -[APMSqliteStore prepareSQL:error:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMSqliteStore_acc99dfbcd8c054676308fb24061e3f7.o)
      +[APMASIdentifierWrapper iOS14OrAbove] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMASIdentifierWrapper_1d59db0ddd97263057318367c9cd40e6.o)
      -[APMIdentity supportsAppTrackingConsentStatus] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMIdentity_ba0d5d0b5e35834ab5a7bf0571075715.o)
      -[APMMeasurement(URL) sendDeepLinkURLToAppDelegateOnMainThread:extraInfo:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMMeasurement+URL_89002570063d654e31cbed7a49d52cf9.o)
      l002 in GoogleMobileAds(GADAugmentedRealitySignalSource.o)
      _GADWindowSceneForViewController in GoogleMobileAds(GADScene.o)
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang:
error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        Ld /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/adMob-govjzfsolrnouaecgeggequoemrv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/adMob.app/adMob normal x86_64
(1 failure)
```

adMob is my project name.I followed all the instruction to install it.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "adMob",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-firebase/admob": "^7.6.5",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^8.4.3",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.11.6",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.11.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "1.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "25.5.1",
    "eslint": "6.8.0",
    "jest": "25.5.4",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.59.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

**Podfile**

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'adMob' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])
  
  pod 'RNFBAdMob', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/admob'

  target 'adMobTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  use_flipper!
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
  end
end

target 'adMob-tvOS' do
  # Pods for adMob-tvOS

  target 'adMob-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end
```

I also added **firebase.json** file in root folder

Answer (score 0):

After I did RND and I found that it was the Xcode version issue. I am using Xcode 10 and it is working on Xcode 11 and higher version. So that's why I am facing this issue.

Comment: i am facing the same problem, my xcode version is 11.3.1. Do you still have the link ? In my case ads are working fine on both android and iPhone but it gives the error during archive

Comment: You should check ios permission to show ads for when you are creating an archive.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Do I need to update my xcode ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes definitely. If you not get ads only archive. then it is mostly permission issue. You should also check google ad mod key which you implemented in react native admod is correct or not.